# How to achieve this selection in TSQL? using AND logical not helping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL statement as shown here, but it's not returning the result I want:

```
select *
from Sales
where Purchased = 'Orange' and Purchased != 'Apple'
```

Table data:

| CustomerID | Customer | Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | Apple |
| 1 | Alex | Orange |
| 2 | Kate | Orange |

My query is returning:

| CustomerID | Name | Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | Orange |
| 2 | Kate | Orange |

But what I want is this:

| CustomerID | Name | Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Kate | Orange |

Comment: what makes {2,Kate,Orange} the thing you "want"?

Comment: Your query reflect the result it generated.

Comment: What is your logic to come up with what you want?

Comment: Your query seeks individual rows where `Purchased` is `'Orange'` and, at the same time, is not `'Apple'`. That's fine as any row with the value `'Orange'` is certainly not `'Apple'`. Your "What I want" indicates that you want to check more than one row at a time, e.g. to find `CustomerID` values which have purchased `'Orange'`, but not `'Apple'`. That's a different problem and, thus far, you haven't explained what logic you have in mind to get "What I want".

Comment: Use `NOT EXISTS` as shown by Stu. There is no better way for such use cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your data it appears you want to exclude any Sales that contain "Apple", which you can easily do with a *not exists* clause:

```
select *
from Sales s
where Purchased = 'Orange' 
and not exists (
  select * from Sales s2
  where s2.Id = s.Id and s2.Purchased = 'Apple'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT 
    oranges.Id, 
    oranges.Customer, 
    oranges.Purchased 
FROM Sales oranges 
LEFT JOIN Sales apples ON oranges.Id = apples.Id AND apples.Purchased = 'Apple'
WHERE oranges.Purchased = 'Orange'
AND apples.Id IS NULL
```

See this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba4d5d/3)

I'm making a few assumptions about your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The logic in your SQL query is returning the expected

> Give me all names where they have purchased an orange, not an apple.

What you want is

> Give me all names where they have purchased an orange, also not purchased an apple.

Do this by aliasing tables and joining them:

```
SELECT orange.CustomerID, orange.Customer, orange.Purchased

FROM Sales orange

LEFT JOIN (SELECT CustomerID FROM SALES WHERE Purchased <> "Apple") apple

ON orange.CustomerID = apple.CustomerID

WHERE orange.Purchased = 'Orange'
```

I always put a TOUPPER or TOLOWER function in my where clauses to ensure clean joins.